# Showing that $\frac{r^2+z^2-a^2+i(2ar)}{r^2+z^2+a^2-2az}= \frac{r+i(z+a)}{r+i(z-a)}$ for real $r$, $a$, $z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

> Consider the expression
> $$ \frac{r^2+z^2-a^2+i(2ar)}{r^2+z^2+a^2-2az}$$
> for real-valued variables $r$, $a$, $z$. Show that this is equivalent to
> $$ \frac{r+i(z+a)}{r+i(z-a)}$$

I came across this problem while trying to show that two transformations (conformal mappings) are equivalent and I was surprised that I couldn't find any logical way forward from the first equation. Sage provides that they are, in fact, equivalent, which is good, and now I only want to show the derivation of the latter equation from the former (i.e. reduce the former equation to the latter, do not simply show that their difference is zero).

I feel in my gut that there's a way by factoring, and multiplying by a complex conjugate, which would introduce the imaginary part in the denominator, but I haven't found anything that works (completing squares, grouping terms and factoring, etc).

Comment: @Blue thanks for the title edit, that's more descriptive

Comment: You can always just cross-multiply and show that you get the same expression. But also ... Note that $r^2+z^2+a^2-2az=r^2+(z-a)^2$, a sum-of-squares that factors into complex conjugates; likewise, $r^2+z^2-a^2+2iar = (r+ia)^2+z^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is equivalent to
$$ \frac {(r+ia)^2 - i^2 z^2} { r^2 - i^2 (z-a)^2 } $$
$$ \frac {(r+ia-iz)(r+ia+iz)}{(r+iz-ia)(r-iz+ia)} $$
$$ \frac {r+i(z+a)}{r+i(z-a)} $$

Comment: This answer is too unspecific as-is, can you show what you mean by factoring and cancellation?

Comment: @SamGallagher Factor numerator as denominator as difference of two squares.

Comment: @saulspatz I know, but it just needs a bit more to be a satisfactory answer IMHO. Edit has fixed it, thanks.

Comment: If it needs more editing , please edit it . I don't know complete Mathjax yet.